# Android GridView 0 position issue

Tags: android, gridview

I know this question is already asked but I didn't get any proper solution to solve 0 position issue. I am working on Gridview and created one adaptor (ButtonAdapter) for this. so I have 4 buttons and If I click any one of them then selected button should change bg color and remaining all three buttons should have reduced opacity let say 0.3 but My problem is that my first button does not change the alpha. So what is the exact issue?

package adaptor;

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import com.appsee.Appsee;
    import com.regiumconsulting.donationssumup.MainActivity;
    import com.regiumconsulting.donationssumup.R;

    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        private final String[] mobileValues;
        private BigDecimal amnt;
        private Button[] chosenone = new Button[1];
        private Button[] tempBtn = null;
        private BigDecimal amount;
        private Map<Button, BigDecimal> buttons = new HashMap<>();

        public ButtonAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
            tempBtn = new Button[mobileValues.length];
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View gridView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                gridView = new View(context);
                // get layout from item_adaptor.xmlor.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_adaptor, null);

            } else {
                gridView = convertView;
            }

            // set image based on selected text
            final Button btnView = (Button) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            setBtnAmnt(position, btnView);

            btnView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_dashed_border);
            tempBtn[position] = btnView;

            btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                 for (int i = 0; i < tempBtn.length; i++) {//set alpha to 0.5 for all buttons
                 tempBtn[i].setAlpha(0.3f);//updating only three buttons bg not for 1st one.
                }
                 chosenone[0] = btnView;

                amount = buttons.get(chosenone[0]);

        chosenone[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_border);//set alpha 1 to selected one and set selected color
                chosenone[0].setAlpha(1f);

         }     
      }  
    });
     return gridView;
  }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mobileValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        private void setBtnAmnt(int position, Button imageView) {
            amnt = new BigDecimal(mobileValues[position]);
            imageView.setText(String.format("£ %s", amnt.toString()));
            buttons.put(imageView, amnt);

        }
    }

    Also, I have created on method inside main activity let say screenClick.

    public void screenClick() {
            gridView.setAdapter(adaptor);
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

So If I call this method and then perform the same operation as mentioned above then only it will work and it will set 0.3 alpha for a 1st button. So what is the issue I don't understand?

I have also attached a screenshot link where a 1st button doesn't have reduced opacity.
https://imgur.com/a/bofGMk4
```

Comment: You said you have 4 buttons in `grid_item_image` . But i am seeing only one button here which is `R.id.grid_item_image`.

Comment: @ADM Yes in Adaptor I have defined one button and it depends on String[] mobileValues length, which I am passing through mainactivity class as a constructor.

Comment: So where is the 4 buttons ? Your question is quite unclear . Attach an screen shot of your grid view .

Comment: @ADM please see this
https://imgur.com/a/bofGMk4

Comment: this is `One button = one grid item`  . Then why are having this array of `Button` in your adapter . I can provide you solution but i can not understand why you have used those `Button` array.

Comment: @ADM please let me know what should I do? but in mainActivity I am doing this

    static final String[] DONATION_PRICE = new String[]{"2.72","11.15","3.27","11.11"};
 //Calling Adaptor
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adaptor = new ButtonAdapter(this, DONATION_PRICE);
        gridView.setAdapter(adaptor);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186033/discussion-between-ashish-jain-and-adm).

Comment: I think a quick fix is also setting alpha of the button as 0.3 in item layout file (xml). Hope that helps!